# Unnumbered `tabu` environments

Tags: numbering, tabu, longtabu

Is it possible to have unnumbered [`tabu`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) environments?  The starred versions of these environments, i.e., `tabu*` and `longtabu*`, do something else entirely.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[version=last, paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[unicode, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to .66\linewidth{X[l,p]}
  \blindtext{} \\
\end{longtabu}
\begin{longtabu} to .66\linewidth{X[l,p]}
  \blindtext{} \\
\end{longtabu}
\begin{longtabu} to .66\linewidth{X[l,p]}
  \captionabove{Blind text}\label{tab:blind-text} \\
  \blindtext{} \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

The captioned table has `Table 3` instead of `Table 1`.

Comment: The `tabu` environments are not numbered per se!

Comment: Could you explain better?  What increments the `table` counter, then?

Comment: `\caption` does when it is used inside a `table` environment

Comment: `\caption` even in `longtabu`. if caption is not used, you have "unnumbered" `tabu` or `longtabu`.

Comment: @Zarko true because `longtabu` (or `longtable` really) changes the definition of `\caption` accordingly

Comment: @d125q, please provide small but complete document (not only code snippet)  which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was missunderstood the question when i write in my comment regarding `lontable` and `longtabu` so my claims was wrong. `longtable` as well `longtabu` (which use `longtable`) have integrated some `caption` facitilities (that caption can be used inside those table environments). this includes increment `table` counter. consequently, this counter is incremented even if `caption` is not presented.

as workaround for your problem is after `\begin{longtable} ...` or `\begin{longtabu} ...` add you add

```
 \addtocounter{table}{-1}
```

Comment: I have oft lamented (to myself...) the incrementation of table counter by `longtable` even if no caption!